# c++ read integer array from console

Tags: c++, input, console

so I have been trying to get out of an infinite loop when reading some numbers from the console. This is the reading part code:

```
vector<int> all;
string input;
while (getline(cin, input)) {
    int number;
    stringstream ss(input);
    while (ss >> number) {
        all.push_back(number);
    }
}
```

I tried this as well:

```
vector<int> all;
while (cin >> number) {
    all.push_back(number);
}
```

Comment: Go with the second example and enter an EOF character to the console (common EOF characters are Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z).

Answer (score -1):

A fast way to solve this is to break the outer loop when entering an empty line from console:

```
while (getline(cin, input))
{
   if (input == "")
       break;
    ...
}
```

**Note:** some implementation return a carriage return at the end of the line in the getline, it stripes only the new line (line feed)
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

As said, this is a very easy and fast way to do an exit from your infinite loop, from the user point of view, he/she can enter numbers separated by spaces, tabs, enter or any combinations and your *vector* will be populated until the user enter an empty line.

your code will look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> all;
    string input;
    while (getline(cin, input)) {
        if (input == "")
            break;
        int number;
        stringstream ss(input);
        while (ss >> number) {
            all.push_back(number);
        }
    }
    // Here the vector "all" has any numbers entered by user
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is my way appropriate for putting all the input numbers in my all vector.

Comment: " some implementation return a carriage return at the end of the line in the getline" - no, they don't.

Comment: "no, they don't", actual up to date implementations don't and the answer target that, but some Embedded systems _**(has happened many times with control systems)**_ with old implementations and working within an environment where line termination is <CR><LF>, remove the ending line feed (ASCII 10 or 0A hex) and left the carriage return (ASCII 13 or 0D hex) so the comparison has to be made as: if (input == "\r")
       break;

Comment: _**"I'm confused. Is my way appropriate for putting all the input numbers in my all vector."**_, depends on the input use and nature, if all data entered are vector elements to be processed in some way, is okay.  If the values are heterogeneous, consider to ask the user what are you waiting for each type, and receive it in different variables (vectors, quantities, limits, etc.).